# Data frame operations: filtering common rows and removing rows of several data frames

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, subset

```
     dfA <- data.frame(Efficiency=c(7,2,8,9), Value=c(3, 4, 7, 8))
     dfB <- data.frame(Efficiency=c(7,2,4,2,8,9), Value=c(3, 4, 4, 1, 7, 8))
     dfC <- data.frame(Efficiency=c(7,9), Value=c(3, 8))
```

I want to get the common rows of dfA and dfB. From the resulting data.frame I want to remove the rows that have the same values as dfC.
dfA+dfB (only common rows) - dfC (overlapping rows)

Comment: so you want to `dfm <- merge(dfA, dfB, by = c("Efficiency", "Value"))` and then subtract `dfm$Value` from `dfC$Value` , which is shorter and has the exact same values??? I am confused, please specifiy what "common rows" means and what should get subtracted from what

Comment: @grrgrrbla : I clarified the description

Comment: Try `subset(merge(dfA, dfB), !(Efficiency %in% dfC$Efficiency & Value %in% dfC$Value))-dfC`

Comment: I am still confused: do you want to subtract the rows or do you want to remove the common rows ?

Comment: @grrgrrbla : I want to select the common rows of dfA & dfB. Lets say the result is dfm. Then I want to remove rows of dfm that are also in dfc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(dfA, dfB) %>% anti_join(dfC)
```

which gives:

```
  Efficiency Value
1          8     7
2          2     4
```

Comment: you have to convert the objects from matrix do a data.frame like so: `dfA <- data.frame(dfA)` , if this answered your question consider accepting the answer by clicking the arrow

Comment: I can't vote up yet. I first need 15 reputation. I will vote you up once I have that. By the way what do I do if I just want to add two data frames? Let's say dfA+dfB ( get all rows of each one together in one data frame) thanks a lot!

Comment: this is not about upvoting its about accepting an answer :) which you can always do after you asked a question, there is a tick-mark next to it which you can click to accept an answer; to answer your question: either `rbind(dfA, dfB)` or `cbind(dfA, dfB)` depending on if you want to bind them column-wise or row-wise